# Are the angle brackets (< or >) special in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regex expression to accept < and > as my outside delimiters to grab all the content in between them.

so content like such

```
< tfdsfa  >
```

should be grabbed.

Do I have to escape the < and > characters or something?

Regex generated by my script:

```
/<[^(>)]*>/g
```

Code from file:

```
data.method.highlight = function() {
    var x = data.syntax,
        text = data.$.span.html();
    for (var i=0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
        var rx;
        if (x[i].range) {
            rx = new RegExp(x[i].tag[0] + "[^(" + x[i].tag[1] + ")]*" + x[i].tag[1], "g");
            console.log(rx);
        }
        else {
            var temprx = x[i].tag[0];
            for (var z = 1; z < x[i].tag.length; z++) {
                temprx += "|" + x[i].tag[z];
            }
            rx = new RegExp(temprx, "g");
        }
        text = text.replace(rx,function (match) {
            console.log("looping - range");
            return '<span class="' + x[i].class.default + '">' + match + '</span>';
        });
        data.$.span.html(text);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your regex works. What exactly is it that you fail to achieve?

Comment: Use this tool any time you are developing regexes: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Can you show how you're using this expression?

Comment: Works for me: http://rubular.com/r/XyPO3QuMrw and http://jsfiddle.net/PMgd3/

Comment: Any chance you have a `</script>` or `<!--` literal in your code?

Comment: Do you just want to match the stuff inside the `<>`?  How about `<([^>]*)>`?

Comment: The expression works when I run it in a exp editor such as regexpal. But in my code it fails to work. EDIT: I added my "highlight" code to the main question

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Neither `<` nor `>` are metacharacters inside a regular expression.

This works for me:

```
'<foo> and <bar>'.match(/<[^>]*>/g); // ["<foo>", "<bar>"]
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit I made. The regex works when I run it in jsfiddle but not in my script. Any idea how that is occurring?

Comment: @MikeDepies, what's the output from the `console.log(rx)`? More specifically, what is the precise string you send to the RegExp constructor, the precise value of `text`, and the result vs. expected value?

Comment: Figured the issue out, thanks to you asking what the text value ended up being. The text was converting the < characters to their html special character counter part. I should have really thought about this before posting. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could be having a problem when you try to insert the result into HTML and the browser *thinks* that it is not a valid HTML tag, like `<blablabla>`.