# Extracting HTML tags from a string

Tags: regex, string

I want to find a html tag inside a string. For example, below is a sample string with html() tag

```
    கொழும்பு:<br /><br />
    இலங்கையின் பல பகுதிகளில் கடந்த 15-ம் தேதியில் இருந்து பெய்துவரும் பரவலான மழையின் விளைவாக நாட்டின் பல பகுதிகள் வெள்ளக்காடாக காட்சியளிக்கின்றன<br /><br />

<br /><br /><br /><img alt="" src="/uploads/0F05DC56CD0857B6E_L_styvpf.gif" height="350" width="615" /><br /><br />
    இந்நிலையில், இலங்கையின் மத்தியப் பகுதியில் தலைநகர் கொழும்புவில் இருந்து சுமார் 140 கிலோமீட்டர் தூரத்தில் உள்ள மலைப்பிரதேசமான அரநாயக பகுதியில் நேற்று பின்னிரவு ஏற்பட்ட நிலச்சரிவால் பாறைகள் உருண்டுவந்து அருகாமையில்
```

How to find, the above string with html tags like image, videos, etc.. in Windows phone. Any help on this would be very appreciable

Comment: Use a regex like `<[^>]+>`

Comment: Thank Wiktor Stribizew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression (regex) to extract the needed information from a string

Comment: Thank you for the response Tayyib. Can u share some samples

Comment: Appearently your question already has an answer. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095039/are-the-angle-brackets-or-special-in-a-regular-expression