# Stop When <br> is Encountered In C# RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am aware that [HTML Should Not Be Parsed With RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Nonetheless, there are exceptions. I am trying to take the following text:

`br > Email: fooBar@yahoo.com<br>Name: Barbara Foo<br> Phone: 888888888<br>Professio`

and regEx out

`Barbara Foo` from it.

The RegEx I am trying to use is `Name: (.*)((?=\\r)|(?=<br>))`. Note that I am trying to [stop capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-to-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-expres) at `<br>` with `(?=<br>)`. This does NOT work. It works perfectly well with any word, phrases, etc, but not `<br>`.

How do I get this to work?

RegEx tester for C# here matches what I see when running locally: http://regexstorm.net/tester

According to my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095039/are-the-angle-brackets-or-special-in-a-regular-expression), angle brackets are not special characters to RegEx.

Comment: Add a `?` to make it not greedy: `Name: (.*?)((?=\\r)|(?=<br>))`

Comment: Why not make it non greedy `.*?` and shorted it `Name: (.*?)(?:\\r|<br>)` You could turn the lookahead in a match if you want the group value.

Comment: Thanks guys, both of those work and solve my problem. I work with RegEx once a year or so, so forgot about it. Still curious why it works for phrases without angle brackets though. Edit: I think that not only solves my immediate problem but also protects me from stuff I didn't anticipate, so double thanks.

Comment: @Thefourthbird care to post an answer? Your's shorter

Comment: @kishkin That is not needed, it is a [common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match) and might qualify as a duplicate.